# Using for_each and boost::bind with a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I have a vector of pointers. I would like to call a function for every element, but that function takes a reference.  Is there a simple way to dereference the elements?

Example:

```
MyClass::ReferenceFn( Element & e ) { ... }

MyClass::PointerFn( Element * e ) { ... }

MyClass::Function()
{
    std::vector< Element * > elements;
    // add some elements...

    // This works, as the argument is a pointer type
    std::for_each( elements.begin(), elements.end(),
                   boost::bind( &MyClass::PointerFn, boost::ref(*this), _1 ) );

    // This fails (compiler error), as the argument is a reference type
    std::for_each( elements.begin(), elements.end(),
                   boost::bind( &MyClass::ReferenceFn, boost::ref(*this), _1 ) );
}
```

I could create a dirty little wrapper that takes a pointer, but I figured there had to be a better way?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `boost::ref(*this)`? I just use: boost::bind(&MyClass::ReferenceFn, this, _1) and it works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `boost::indirect_iterator`:

```
std::for_each( boost::make_indirect_iterator(elements.begin()), 
               boost::make_indirect_iterator(elements.end()),
               boost::bind( &MyClass::ReferenceFn, boost::ref(*this), _1 ) );
```

That will dereference the adapted iterator twice in its `operator*`.

Comment: +1, although for this case I prefer `BOOST_FOREACH(Element *e, elements) this->ReferenceFn(*e);`. C++ may be usable as a functional language, but not as a *concise* functional language...

Comment: And the Python would be `for e in elements: self.ReferenceFn(e)`. It's heart-breaking.

Comment: For C++0x it will be `for(auto *e : elements) ReferenceFn(*e);`. Sweet :)

Comment: I'm considering starting to call it C++JamTomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could also use the [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/lambda.html) library.

```
// Appears to compile with boost::lambda::bind
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    std::for_each( elements.begin(), elements.end(),
                   bind( &MyClass::ReferenceFn, boost::ref(*this), *_1 ) );
```

But I agree with the commenters about preferring `BOOST_FOREACH`. The `for_each` "algorithm" does practically nothing useful, and what it does, range-based for loop can do for you with a much smaller effort.