# Using find_if and boost::bind with a set of shared_pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-bind

I have a vector of shared_ptr, I want to combine boost shared_ptr and bind together.

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413786/using-for-each-and-boostbind-with-a-vector-of-pointers), except that instead of "&MyClass::ReferenceFn" I would like to call "&Element::Fn".

Here is a similar piece of code:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< Vertex > vertex_ptr; 
std::set<vertex_ptr> vertices;

void B::convert()
{
...
if( std::find_if(boost::make_indirect_iterator(vertices.begin()), 
                 boost::make_indirect_iterator(vertices.end() ),  boost::bind( &Vertex::id, boost::ref(*this), _1 ) == (*it)->id() ) == vertices.end() )
}
```

here is the error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::reference_wrapper<B>, boost::arg<1>&)’
```

**NOTE**: I am limited to use the C++03.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, the error is that it take (this keyword) as this pointer of class B

Comment: then perpahs you want `boost::bind(&Vertex::id, _1) == (*it)->id())`, or, `boost::bind(static_cast<int(Vertex::*)()>(&Vertex::id), _1) == (*it)->id())` (where `int` is the return type of `id`)

Comment: thank you very much, if you provide you comment as an answer I will choose it as best solution. and Also will you please explain me what star means in "(Vertex::*) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a member function for each object stored in a collection, you need to use a placeholder as the first bound argument of the `boost::bind`:

```
boost::bind(&Vertex::id, _1) == (*it)->id())
//                       ~^~
```

This way, each argument `a`, will be bound to a member function pointer, and called as `(a.*&Vertex::id)()`.

However, seeing that the error message says `unresolved overloaded function type`, it draws a conclusion that your class `Vertex` can have multiple overloads of member function `id`. As such, the compiler is unable to tell which one it should pass as the argument of `boost::bind`. To solve this, use an explicit cast to a member function pointer (the asterisk after colon indicates it's a pointer to a member):

```
boost::bind(static_cast<int(Vertex::*)()const>(&Vertex::id), _1) == (*it)->id())
//                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

In the case class `Vertex` has multiple overloads, say:

```
int id() const { return 0; }
void id(int i) { }
```

you will use the first one for binding.